# Error in using the PHP mail() function

Tags: smtp, php

I would like to develop a simple  email function in my PHP file, so I'm using the `mail()` function. When I try to send an email to myself, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
$subject = "Hi";
$message = "Hello";
$from = "me@hello.com";
$header = "Form:".$from;
mail($from, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Here is the error message:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\NFC\back.php on line 171
```

I think it is probably because the port is being used by other applications, so I tried to make changes to the php.ini file as follows:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 8080
```

However, it still gives the same message. What are the possible causes of this problem?

Comment: The prototype for the `mail()` function is: `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`. So, for starters, the first parameter isn't `$from`.

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server running on your local machine? And, in the header, it should be "from", not "form".

Comment: Your SMTP server isn't running, or can't be connected to.  You should post with the details about your SMTP server and its configuration... that is the relevant problem.

Comment: ya, I have it, I know the first parameter should not be from, but as it is just a test, so i just simply want to send an email back to my account to have a test

Comment: May I ask how can I output the details of my SMTP server?

Comment: I have checked in the server manager, a SMTP server should have installed in my window server 2008 system, so isn't it should be running continuously?